# Javascript alert inside a function running on its own

Tags: javascript

I have a function whose whole purpose is to run an alert which displays a message from a variable. Whenever I run the program, however, the alert runs on its own immediately, and never when I click the button that's supposed to trigger the function. I don't know why this is able to happen, so any help would be appreciated.

**The Function**

```
function finalTally(){
    alert(solutionStatement)
  }
```

**The Button (a small part of a larger return statement)**

```
<div className="solutionBox">
    <button onClick={finalTally()}>Go</button>
</div>
```

Comment: And what framework ar you using? My guess is they want you to bind events like `onClick={finalTally}`, but not knowing the framework, it is a guess

Comment: Get rid of the `{}`, just write `onclick="finalTally()"`. Your framework is evaluating what's inside `{}` immediately.

Comment: I've loaded this from an index.html and on Codepen and it does not alert until I click the button. Could something else be causing it? Are you calling `finalTally()` elsewhere in you js?

Answer (score 2):

Probably the function is running automatticaly since you are calling it right away by using (), you could use this notation to only run when you click  it:

`<button onClick={() => finalTally()}>Go</button>`

Or just pass the function without ():

`<button onClick={finalTally}>Go</button>`

Comment: unless this isn't vanilla JS the first option throws an error and the second does nothing when the button is clicked. What am I missing about your solutions?

Comment: Due to the use of {} insted of "" I´m assuming it´s not Vanilla JS, besides that, this error of running the function automatticaly is very common on frameworks like React.